# Service Layer Design Question

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services

I am looking for a .NET solution to the following scenario. Expect any known frameworks, solutions or some design ideas to design this component.

We have a WCF service that makes call backs to clients connected to update their UI. A simple example : When lets say 10 users are connected to this service and 1 user updates a grid record and saves it, the service makes a call back to update UI in the other 9 clients. This service is doing a lot many things and hence this direct connections with clients slows this down and we forsee some problems as the number of clients grow. So, we are thinking to add another layer where the client and service talk to for listening and broadcasting their messages/events.

I am looking for a solution, where like a message bus or message broker or pub-sub model framework or idea, where the client and service is decoupled. This could also be used in a distributed environment facility. Wondering does WCF offer any facility for this or some known solutons or design ideas would help or also wondering solutions like ESB are a overkilling for such scenarios or do we have anything like ESB but light weight from MS or will MSMQ simply solve this scenario.

Many Thanks,
Mani

Comment: It may help to describe the clients in more detail (i.e. WinForm, browser-based apps, java, etc.) The requirement that should drive the message bus/broker scenario is whether guaranteed delivery is required. If it's OK for client to occasionally miss notifications then something more lightweight could be used. Here [are some good thoughts](http://www.udidahan.com/2008/11/01/soa-eda-and-cep-a-winning-combo/) in this area.

Comment: It is a trading platform based on winforms.

Answer (score 0):

This is really hard to answer because, as with many questions like this, it all depends on a lot of factors that are not given.

1. The number of clients. There are many levels and solutions in between 10 and 500.000.000 (concurrent) clients. It is also important to know the amount of **concurrent** clients and whether or not clients that are not connected need to be signaled when they are back online.
2. Technology. If multiple client platforms must be supported the choices will be very different.
3. Architecture. You mentioned an ESB. The scenario you describe is hardly ever the (leading) reason to develop an ESB. So if there are no other reasons to develop an ESB I'd stay away from that path. On the other hand, if an ESB is present it could solve your problem quite easily depending on the given ESB. (I might be wrong here as it might be possible that I consider an ESB something entirely different from what you intended)
4. Security. In a multi-platform environment security can be a beast to tame but at the same time be crucial. So the security requirements are potentially a very influential factor.
5. Reliability. How bad is it when a client misses a message? Depending on the answer the design could be very different.
6. Durability. If you need to restore your system by loading a backup what do you expect the messaging system to do?
7. Performance. How fast should it be? Lots of consequences here. The difference between a message being delivered with a day and a message delivered within 10 seconds is huge.

As long as these factors (and I left out quite a few) are unknown it is nearly impossible to give a fitting solution.

All the technologies you mentioned are valid but there are many more and there are all kinds of configurations and combinations possible.

Comment: It is a trading platform based on winforms. We are also looking thinking the same solution can be put to use between two services. We have scnearios where a service A1 sends messages to other service A and we are thinking to create service A2, A3, A4 for a distributed scenario. So, we expect the same solution would be a fit for this scenario as well.

Comment: I am sorry but this doesn't answer any of my questions.